# Month,Year with Value Plot,Pandas and MatPlotLib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i have DataFrame with Month,Year and Value and i want to do a TimeSeries Plot.

Sample:

```
month   year    Value
12      2016    0.006437804129357764
1       2017    0.013850880792606646
2       2017    0.013330349031207292
3       2017    0.07663058273768052
4       2017    0.7822831457266424
5       2017    0.8089573099244689
6       2017    1.1634845000200715
```

im trying to plot this Value data with Year and Month, Year and Month in X-Axis and Value in Y-Axis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting timestamps (hour/minute/seconds) with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709823/plotting-timestamps-hour-minute-seconds-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df['date'] = df['month'].map(str)+ '-' +df['year'].map(str)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m-%Y').dt.strftime('%m-%Y')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot_date(df['date'], df['Value'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is the approach i thought of doing, but didn't know about using map function.

Comment: not all the month-year is visible in the x-axis!, some are hidden, is due to the graph size?

Comment: You can try to rotate them with `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`

Comment: can u post the image?

Comment: Try adding: `positions = [p for p in df['date']]` `labels = [l for l in positions]` 
`ax.set_xticks(positions)` `ax.set_xticklabels(labels)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `DateTime` index for pandas to properly plot the axis. A one line modification for your dataframe (assuming you don't need `year` and `month` anymore as columns and that first day of each month is correct) would do:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime({
    'day': 1,
    'month': df.pop('month'),
    'year': df.pop('year')
}), inplace=True)

df.Value.plot()
```