# How to reduce the x-axis ticks in matplotlib and still spread them over the whole x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code to  plot 6 subfigures with a common x-axis in matplotlib (the first subfigure contains many diagrams):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file_path = r"C:\Users\wi9632\Desktop\Results_End_MultiOpt\Load_Profile_Figure\Combined_Table.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';', encoding='latin-1')


methods = {
    "Dichotomous Method [kW]": ("Dichotomous Method", "tab:orange"),
    "Conventional Control [kW]": ("Conventional Control", "tab:purple"),
    "NSGA-II [kW]": ("NSGA-II", "tab:cyan"),
    "SPEA-II [kW]": ("SPEA-II", "gold"),
    "PALSS [kW]": ("PALSS", "red"),
    "RELAPALLS [kW]": ("RELAPALLS", "lawngreen")
}


fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 1, figsize=(12, 20), sharex=True)

# Plotting the first subplot with 6 lines and adding legend
for method, (name, color) in methods.items():
    axes[0].plot(df["time of day"], df[method], label=name, color=color)
axes[0].set_ylabel("Power [kW]")
axes[0].set_title("Power Profiles for Different Methods")
axes[0].legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.15), ncol=3)


variables = ["Space Heating [kW]", "DHW [kW]", "Availability of the EV", "Outside Temperature [°C]", "Price [Cent/kWh]"]
for i, variable in enumerate(variables, start=1):
    axes[i].plot(df["time of day"], df[variable], color='blue')
    axes[i].set_ylabel(variable)

plt.xlabel("Time of Day")
plt.xticks(range(0, 24), [f"{hour:02d}:00" for hour in range(24)])
plt.tight_layout()


combined_output_path = r"C:\Users\wi9632\Desktop\Results_End_MultiOpt\Load_Profile_Figure\ParetoFronts_combined.png"
plt.savefig(combined_output_path, dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

I want to have the x-axis with this data

```
timeslot    time of day Price [Cent/kWh]    Space Heating [kW]  DHW [kW]    Electricity [kW]    Availability of the EV  Energy Consumption of the EV [kWh]  Outside Temperature [°C]    Dichotomous Method [kW] Conventional Control [kW]   NSGA-II [kW]    SPEA-II [kW]    PALSS [kW]  RELAPALLS [kW]
1   00:00   51  44  47  84  47  46  8   26  37  9   7   40  70
2   00:30   96  94  11  31  70  82  56  79  10  76  6   87  6
3   01:00   58  83  29  12  50  96  92  67  72  96  13  45  35
4   01:30   17  95  87  48  94  58  55  70  66  50  96  31  97
5   02:00   42  98  2   45  71  95  63  58  26  68  24  81  21
6   02:30   67  53  83  64  1   100 97  6   80  30  43  70  10
7   03:00   53  68  6   85  57  78  96  72  39  65  55  48  19
8   03:30   64  55  61  30  54  45  79  56  96  64  74  51  96
9   04:00   63  84  25  76  21  41  39  7   82  36  97  24  91
10  04:30   94  21  9   25  75  76  62  84  76  29  62  40  11
11  05:00   42  16  78  84  41  81  87  42  78  47  38  38  16
12  05:30   100 23  30  87  61  48  78  21  60  40  96  44  83
13  06:00   66  37  84  16  63  90  70  86  73  9   34  10  54
14  06:30   71  86  29  44  25  32  40  43  71  38  18  7   54
15  07:00   47  18  36  83  35  64  6   35  97  42  70  43  83
16  07:30   73  51  44  45  89  23  49  59  7   0   11  51  1
17  08:00   57  63  20  14  17  14  40  86  29  2   58  89  26
18  08:30   26  48  57  32  90  78  82  40  93  82  18  51  41
19  09:00   6   87  5   47  32  38  88  17  64  12  69  53  29
20  09:30   10  98  15  3   27  2   69  30  19  17  75  39  54
21  10:00   70  96  51  49  20  94  66  37  77  93  99  75  63
22  10:30   52  78  39  69  3   26  4   30  68  36  14  49  47
23  11:00   46  46  53  8   32  95  79  79  79  52  74  99  14
24  11:30   73  0   1   60  50  4   37  22  84  75  34  10  11
25  12:00   7   95  84  88  71  0   39  28  39  22  56  27  1
26  12:30   54  18  73  88  94  82  32  51  6   90  41  37  61
27  13:00   79  66  64  12  56  94  76  54  19  9   19  29  38
28  13:30   54  34  2   33  77  94  68  10  80  78  59  6   76
29  14:00   57  43  35  7   58  35  70  68  50  15  64  97  65
30  14:30   75  50  18  97  54  52  5   76  63  56  96  21  81
31  15:00   31  19  30  14  15  54  5   21  95  74  90  51  36
32  15:30   47  40  79  52  15  50  34  61  41  79  84  47  54
33  16:00   95  9   61  47  21  18  78  13  81  43  12  34  95
34  16:30   41  12  84  45  89  71  90  4   7   29  37  90  63
35  17:00   18  78  25  6   69  43  12  44  5   91  99  99  12
36  17:30   69  54  41  98  23  72  63  97  24  18  14  22  25
37  18:00   56  9   76  47  6   89  14  45  17  24  33  80  10
38  18:30   39  43  7   43  28  97  35  79  63  8   82  34  99
39  19:00   27  87  98  34  3   48  100 21  2   53  3   12  54
40  19:30   61  57  55  28  81  55  86  11  48  46  34  87  35
41  20:00   27  24  49  32  10  59  91  69  97  93  31  35  45
42  20:30   79  65  87  72  17  78  71  1   51  43  87  59  53
43  21:00   92  40  7   88  90  58  58  50  100 86  42  13  55
44  21:30   40  31  86  78  47  8   11  30  65  52  54  77  59
45  22:00   53  80  30  25  70  66  11  79  85  3   45  95  86
46  22:30   30  0   55  21  53  0   29  46  53  32  64  41  39
47  23:00   4   33  50  1   31  6   21  90  12  55  88  38  36
48  23:30   58  41  76  5   85  48  83  17  7   77  99  11  36
```

. There should be a tick for every hour of the day. So at 00:00, 01:00, 02:00 (but the data should be plotted in a time resolution of 30 minutes). The code above creates the following x-axis:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The x-axis ticks are not spread over the whole length of the x-axis. So the tick for 00:00 should be on the very left while the last tick at 23:00 should be (almost) on the very right.

Update: when using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file_path = r"C:\Users\wi9632\Desktop\Results_End_MultiOpt\Load_Profile_Figure\Combined_Table.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';', encoding='latin-1')



methods = {
    "Dichotomous Method [kW]": ("Dichotomous Method", "tab:orange"),
    "Conventional Control [kW]": ("Conventional Control", "tab:purple"),
    "NSGA-II [kW]": ("NSGA-II", "tab:cyan"),
    "SPEA-II [kW]": ("SPEA-II", "gold"),
    "PALSS [kW]": ("PALSS", "red"),
    "RELAPALLS [kW]": ("RELAPALLS", "lawngreen")
}


fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 1, figsize=(12, 20), sharex=True)

# Plotting the first subplot with 6 lines and adding legend
for method, (name, color) in methods.items():
    axes[0].plot(df["time of day"], df[method], label=name, color=color)
axes[0].set_ylabel("Power [kW]")
axes[0].set_title("Power Profiles for Different Methods")
axes[0].legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.15), ncol=3)



variables = ["Space Heating [kW]", "DHW [kW]", "Availability of the EV", "Outside Temperature [°C]", "Price [Cent/kWh]"]
for i, variable in enumerate(variables, start=1):
    axes[i].plot(df["time of day"], df[variable], color='blue')
    axes[i].set_ylabel(variable)

# for ax in axes:
ax = axes[-1]
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
ax.set_xticks([i for i, lbl in enumerate(labels) if
lbl.get_text().endswith('00')])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)


plt.xlabel("Time of Day")
plt.tight_layout()




combined_output_path = r"C:\Users\wi9632\Desktop\Results_End_MultiOpt\Load_Profile_Figure\ParetoFronts_combined.png"
plt.savefig(combined_output_path, dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

The diagramms looks as they should but there is one problem. There is too much empty white space before the first tick (00:00) and after the last tick (23:00). Also the diagramms don't begin and end at the very left and right but just there is white space (as you can also see on the previously posted screenshots)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUucl.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE6VR.png

Comment: What is the data type of your time of day column?

Comment: @Jared: The data is as posted above: "00:00", "01:00", ..."23:00". These are hours of the day

Comment: No, I'm asking what you get when you print `df["time of day"].dtype`. You probably want to do `df["time of day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time of day"])` before plotting. Try that and comment out `plt.xticks(...)` line to see what that gives you.

Comment: The types is object and when using your code the labels have undesired values like 02-22 00

Comment: With your new data, what problem do you have with `df["time of day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time of day"], format="%H:%M")`? Are you using the latest pandas and matplotlib versions? Please also update and test your code with the test data. Please remove the very unhealthy `plt.xticks(range(0, 24), [f"{hour:02d}:00" for hour in range(24)])`. Please add the call to `ax.margins(x=0)`

Comment: @JohanC: Thanks for your comment. I posted my current code that puts the ticks on the right place but there is too much empty space left and right from the diagramms. By the way, using `df["time of day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time of day"], format="%H:%M")` is a very bad idea as no diagramm graph is displayed and the labels are somewhere weirdly on the right bottom corner

Comment: You didn't include `ax.margins(x=0)` (which is meant to remove the extra whitespace).  Using `df["time of day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time of day"], format="%H:%M")` is a very good idea.  But you can't use `ax.set_xticks(...)` when you use matplotlib's automatic data/time formatting. `ax.set_xticks(...)` removes all the goodness of `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab the generated x tick labels, iterate through them and keep the positions of the ones that end in '00'.

```py
# for ax in axes:
ax = axes[-1]
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
ax.set_xticks([i for i, lbl in enumerate(labels) if 
lbl.get_text().endswith('00')])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
```

Comment: Thanks Johan for your answer. When using your code I get the error "NameError: name 'ax' is not defined. Did you mean: 'max'?" Where exactly shall I insert it

Comment: They probably didn't realize you were using subplots and named your variable `axes`. Replace `ax` with `axes[-1]` in this answer. That will work on the bottom-most `Axes` object.

Comment: @Jared: Thanks for your answer. When using the code of JohanC (updated version) still the ticks don't span over the whole x-axis

Comment: @PeterBe  To answer this, you need to provide reproducible test data.  You really need to remove `plt.xticks(range(0, 24), [f"{hour:02d}:00" for hour in range(24)])`.  Does `"time of day"` contain arbitrary hours and minutes? Or are they nicely every 15 minutes?  If they are arbitrary, you need to convert them to a date time format.

Comment: @JohanC: Thanks for your answer and effort. Actually, now it looks okay and there are only some minor issues: there appaears to be a 24th value in the data such that the x-axis ticks can go until 24:00 (altough the daytime stopps there). Is this possible to realize? Further, there is a lot of empty space between and after the graphs. This needs to be reduced such that the lines start at 00:00 and end at 23:00 (or 24:00)

Comment: @JohanC: Thanks Johan for your answer anad effort. I really appreciate it. When using your suggested code, I get the error `AttributeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute 'set_margins'. Did you mean: 'set_xmargin'?` When using `axes[-1].set_xmargin(x=0)` I get the error `TypeError: _AxesBase.set_xmargin() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'`

Comment: Regarding the data: I am not allowed to share the data. This is why I did not upload any data. I posted a screenshot of the x label axis data and there you can see, that `time of day` has an entry for every 30 minutes

Comment: You can use `ax.margins(x=0)` or `ax.set_xmargin(0)` (did you know you can [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=matplotlib+set_xmargin) functions to know their parameters?). Please don't upload your data. Please create a minimal example of test data that reproduces your issue.  Please clearly describe your data.  A screenshot is a no-no, as it doesn't tell the exact type, nor tells whether it is a snapshot or the full data. Why do you tell `time of day` has an entry for every 30 minutes, while you also tell *"the data should be plotted in a time resolution of 15 minutes"*?

Comment: @JohanC: Thanks for your answer. When using `ax.margins(x=0)` or `ax.set_xmargin(0)` I don't get an error but the empty space left to 00:00 and right to 23:00 remain the same. Regarding the time resolution, I have to admit, that I made a mistake. The data has a time resolution of 30 minutes (and not 15 minutes as wrongly stated in the question). So there are 48 values for one day

Comment: Your question is really hard to solve without reproducible test data. Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78041881/edit) your post, add test data, add where exactly you're calling `ax.margins` and remove the screenshot of the data? @jared's answer shows a possible way to create test data. You need to check whether his approach is similar enough to your real data to reproduce the issues.   If you want help, you need to allow people helping you.

Comment: @JohanC. Thanks Johan for your comment. I posted some random test data in the question. The data itself does not make any sense but the structure is the same as in the original data

Comment: Thanks for your huge effort JohanC. It was really helpful and it solved my problem. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `"time of day"` column is not a datetime type, so you should first convert it to that.

```py
df["time of day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time of day"], format="%H:%M")
```

Then, to plot the appropriate format you can adjust the date formatting using matplotlib's `DateFormatter` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17710394/12131013)). You can set the tick frequency using the `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator` along with `mpl.dates.HourLocator` with a 1 hour frequency. Finally, you can set the range using the maximum and minimum times.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df["time of day"], df["Electricity [kW]"])
xfmt = mpl.dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.dates.HourLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=45)
ax.set_xlim([df["time of day"].min(), df["time of day"].max()])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually I would like to keep the structure of my code posted above. JohanC actually has a solution with some minor drawbacks (see comment). When trying to incoorporate your solution, espacially `df["time of day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time of day"], format="%H:%M")` in my base code, the results don't look good as nothing is beeing displayed on the diagramms and the x-label ticks look quite bad

Comment: My answer doesn't require major changes to your code. You say it "looks quite bad", but I don't know what you see. You're going to have to provide more information.

Comment: @PeterBe I updated my answer to set the tick frequency.