# matplotlib - plot wrong datetime

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, python-datetime

I'd plot a figure with matplotlib in which the x-axis there are timestamp with yy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss. I have ts in datetime64 (pandas series) and to show also (right) minutes and seconds i follow the hint in this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090383/plotting-unix-timestamps-in-matplotlib) using date2num. The problem is that it plots no-sense dates:[image]

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md   
for df in dfs:
    datenums=md.date2num(df.toPandas()["timestamp"])
    plt.xticks(rotation=25)
    xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
    plt.plot(datenums,x)
    plt.show()
```

where df.toPandas()["timestamp"] is:

```
0   2015-12-15 03:53:13
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I tried to convert datetime64 in datetime but the result doesn't change.

Comment: Can you post some code that reproduces this problem? see [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Why do you think the tick labels are wrong?  The ticks are evenly spaced, not placed.  If you want to control exactly where the ticks are placed, use ad `FixedLocator` for the xaxis major locator.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your timestamp values on **seconds**, use this to create a list for all the tick labels and then add them to the plot considering your data is related to an array of timestamps

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime

OX_ticks_name = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in arrayTmstmp]
OX_ticks_pos = np.arange(0,len(arrayTmstmp))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9), dpi=100)
...
ax.set_xticks(OX_ticks_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(OX_ticks_name, rotation=40, horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=10)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Of course, the position of each tick and the name for each can be configured as you want.