# How to parse this log to get date/time out for plotting with Python3

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, parsing, timestamp

I've got a log that looks like this:

```
 **  &nbspWed; Feb 20 2019 at 12:38:10:734 PM :  ** **  &nbspGnssLocationListener; \- 41** \- onSatelliteStatusChanged() : fixCount = 7                                                                                          
 **  &nbspWed; Feb 20 2019 at 12:38:12:742 PM :  ** **  &nbspGnssLocationListener; \- 41** \- onSatelliteStatusChanged() : fixCount = 7                                                                                          
 **  &nbspWed; Feb 20 2019 at 12:38:14:721 PM :  ** **  &nbspGnssLocationListener; \- 41** \- onSatelliteStatusChanged() : fixCount = 7                                                                                          
 **  &nbspWed; Feb 20 2019 at 12:38:16:777 PM :  ** **  &nbspGnssLocationListener; \- 41** \- onSatelliteStatusChanged() : fixCount = 7                                                                                          
 **  &nbspWed; Feb 20 2019 at 12:38:18:729 PM :  ** **  &nbspGnssLocationListener; \- 41** \- onSatelliteStatusChanged() : fixCount = 7                                                                                           
 **  &nbspWed; Feb 20 2019 at 12:38:20:700 PM :  ** **  &nbspGnssLocationListener; \- 41** \- onSatelliteStatusChanged() : fixCount = 7                                                                                           
 **  &nbspWed; Feb 20 2019 at 12:38:22:697 PM :  ** **  &nbspGnssLocationListener; \- 41** \- onSatelliteStatusChanged() : fixCount = 7                                                                                           
 **  &nbspWed; Feb 20 2019 at 12:38:24:706 PM :  ** **  &nbspGnssLocationListener; \- 41** \- onSatelliteStatusChanged() : fixCount = 7                                                                                           
 **  &nbspWed; Feb 20 2019 at 12:38:26:783 PM :  ** **  &nbspGnssLocationListener; \- 41** \- onSatelliteStatusChanged() : fixCount = 7
```

I'm trying to get the following data from this:

```
12:38:10 PM , 7
12:38:12 PM , 7
12:38:14 PM , 7
12:38:16 PM , 7
12:38:18 PM , 7
...
```

And I'm trying to do this with what I know in Python...Which is pretty rudimentary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import time
import csv

data = []
datafile = open('fix_count_02-20-2019-day.txt' , 'r')
datareader = csv.reader((x.replace('\0','') for x in datafile), delimiter=':')
for row in datareader:
        data.append(row)


np_data = np.asarray(data)
print(np_data)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.xticks( rotation=25 )
ax=plt.gca()
#xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.plot(np_data)

plt.show()
```

I've tried some gymnastics with `split` and `join`, but this didn't really work out for me...I ultimately want to plot this similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090383/plotting-unix-timestamps-in-matplotlib) question, probably (I'm guessing) with a numpy array :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the log file name is log.txt

```
with open('log.txt', 'r') as log:
    lines = log.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        print('{} {} , {}'.format(line[29:37], line[42:44], line[-1]))
```

Output

```
12:38:10 PM , 7
12:38:12 PM , 7
12:38:14 PM , 7
12:38:16 PM , 7
12:38:18 PM , 7
12:38:20 PM , 7
12:38:22 PM , 7
12:38:24 PM , 7
12:38:26 PM , 7
```

Comment: That's assuming the length of the lines in the log never change.

Comment: You are right. It is based on the example you have submitted. Add more details if this is not the situation

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Updated the question as I only just realized you were trying to use numpy to plot the results, not parse the data.

You're going to want to use a simple regex pattern to parse this log file.  You can produce a list of results to do with what you please.

Here is the regex pattern than will parse out your time and `fixCount` into match groups:

```
.*((?:\d{2}:){3}\d{3} (?:PM|AM)).*fixCount = (\d+)
```

Link to it in action: https://regexr.com/48ph8

Please see https://pythonicways.wordpress.com/2016/12/20/log-file-parsing-in-python/ for a good example of how to do what you want.

The solution will be something like this:

```
import re

log_file_path = 'fix_count_02-20-2019-day.txt'
regex = r'.*((?:\d{2}:){3}\d{3} (?:PM|AM)).*fixCount = (\d+)'

match_list = []
with open(log_file_path, 'r') as file:
    data = f.read()
    for match in re.finditer(regex, data, re.S):
        match_text = match.group(0), match.group(1)
        match_list.append(match_text)
        print match_text

# do something with match_list here
```

Comment: This works, but the data is already parsed...Each entry looks like what was shown in the example data.  I need to get the date and fixCount into a 2xN numpy array

Comment: Hmm, so you are trying to turn the parsed data INTO a graph?