# How to use map and lambda function to convert a column in pandas to datetime?

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time

I have a column that has time like 9:3:15 (no leading 0s) (3 mins and 15 sec past 9). I would like to plot this (no date, just time) on the x axis. so i tried the following code:

```
def data_vis(dayN):
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    plt.xticks( rotation=25 )
    ax=plt.gca()
    #ax.xaxis_date()
    xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%MM:%S')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
    plt.plot_date(md.date2num(dayN["Time Stamp"]),dayN["Temperature(deg C)"])
    plt.show()
```

I got the following error:

> DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date; this usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()

with `ax.xaxis_date()` enabled, I got the below error.

> 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Since that columns was "str", I thought of using

`pd.to_datetime(day2["Time Stamp"], format = '%H:%M:%S)`

but it results in the below output:

> 1900-01-01 09:51:33

Now I would like to try `datetime.datetime.strptime` using map and/or lambda function for the above said column..

Any help regarding implementation of map function and plotting the data would be really helpful.Also wil the `datetime.strptime` help in resolving the problem?

thanks,

Comment: to clarify: `day2["Time Stamp"]` has strings representing time, no date. it only holds data within one day, i.e. the date does not change?

Comment: @MrFuppes yes that's right!

Comment: ok did you try to convert the column `day2["Time Stamp"]` to datetime (just don't care about the date) and then pass it to `plt`, without any further conversion?

Comment: I just tried it and it shows only the H:00:00 in the x-axis !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what's going wrong here; the following works fine for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
# create a dummy df...
dayN = pd.DataFrame({"Temperature(deg C)": np.random.rand(10)+20,
                     "Time Stamp": ['9:3:15','9:3:16','9:3:17','9:3:18','9:3:19',
                                    '9:3:20','9:3:21','9:3:22','9:3:23','9:3:24']})
# format to datetime, don't care about the date:
dayN["Time Stamp"] = pd.to_datetime(dayN["Time Stamp"], format='%H:%M:%S')

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
ax = plt.gca()
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.plot_date(md.date2num(dayN["Time Stamp"]), dayN["Temperature(deg C)"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think that because of the no. of entries in my data, matplotlib only shows hourly time like 9:00:00 , 12:00:00 15:00:00. I read it from the comments to the ans here [link]here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/4091264/12129327  thanks for a solution really appreciate it!

Comment: @SomasundharamSampath: maybe you need to set custom ticks then, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790378/how-to-get-ticks-every-hour) or [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date_index_formatter.html)